# Cargo build (BPF) stuck

Tags: ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo, solana, solana-cli

I'm in the process of deploying the [Solana helloworld](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/tree/master/src/program-rust) example smart contract on Ubuntu 20.04. When running `npm run build:program-rust`, the `package.json` in the root of the repository states that this corresponds with `cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program-rust/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/program`. However, when running this command compilation is stuck without any indicators, even when appending the verbosity tag to the cargo build command.

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and only took the following steps:

- `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- Install NodeJS v14.x and build-essential
- Install Rust: `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`
- Install Solana CLI: `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.8.6/install)"`
- `git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld.git`

When running `which cargo-build-bpf`, Ubuntu points towards the directory `~/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.8.6/solana-release/bin/cargo-build-bpf`, indicating that the PATH variable has been updated correctly.

The Cargo.toml file looks as follows:

```
[package]
name = "solana-bpf-helloworld"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "Example template program written in Rust"
authors = ["Solana Maintainers <maintainers@solana.com>"]
repository = "https://github.com/solana-labs/solana"
license = "Apache-2.0"
homepage = "https://solana.com/"
edition = "2018"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []

[dependencies]
borsh = "0.9.3"
borsh-derive = "0.9.1"
solana-program = "~1.10.35"

[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "~1.10.35"
solana-sdk = "~1.10.35"

[lib]
name = "helloworld"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

Yesterday, I tried deleting the Cargo.lock file and running `cargo update`. It got stuck on trying to retrieve the `Borsh` crate which is also specified in the Cargo.toml file. I don't exactly know the relevance of this, but it seems worth pointing out.

Comment: There's an extra tool around 300M required to be download to work. I experienced the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you run `cargo build-bpf`, the command silently fetches the SDK required to build the program, which can take some time. There's no indication while that's happening, unfortunately.

You may need to reinstall the Solana CLI, try again, and be sure to wait long enough.

Comment: I've build all the solana toolchain and cli, Should I recompile them?